# Haskell: cannot compile the program

Tags: haskell

I cannot compile the following code:

```
main = do 
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn (work (toInt line) [0,0,0])

work n b = do
  if n == 0 
    then 
        unwords (map show b)
    else do 
        line <- getLine
        work n-1 summ (map toInt . unwords line) b

toInt :: String -> Int
toInt b = read b

toInts a = map toInt a

summ [] [] = []
summ (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+y) ++ (summ xs ys)
```

Here is the error:

```
src\Main.hs:28:21:
Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `IO String'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression: line <- getLine
In the expression:
  do { line <- getLine;
         work n - 1 summ (map toInt . unwords line) b }
In the expression:
  if n == 0 then
      unwords (map show b)
  else
      do { line <- getLine;
             work n - 1 summ (map toInt . unwords line) b }
```

What I expect from the program is to read

```
n
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
...
a_n b_n c_n
```

and output

```
sum(a) sum(b) sum(c)
```

Could You please explain why the fist occurence of getLine is OK, but the following is not?

***EDIT1***

I fixed the work function as follows:

```
work :: Int -> [Int] -> String
work n b = do
if n == 0 
    then 
        return $ unwords (map show b)
    else do 
        line <- getLine
        work (n-1) (summ toInts.words line b)
```

And the error is now:

```
src\Main.hs:27:13:
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
Expected type: String
  Actual type: [String]
In the expression: return $ unwords (map show b)
In the expression:
  if n == 0 then
        return $ unwords (map show b)
  else
      do { line <- getLine;
           work (n - 1) (summ toInts . words line b) }
```

***EDIT2***
Here is the final working prog:

```
main = do 
line <- getLine
ans <- (work (toInt line) [0,0,0])
putStrLn ans

work 0 b = return $ unwords (map show b)
work n b = do
line <- getLine
work (n-1) $ zipWith (+) (map toInt (words line)) b

toInt b = read b::Int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `work` isn't in the `IO` monad: you can fix this by making the `then` part of the if-statement read: `return $ unwords (map show b)`.

Explicit type-signatures are an **extremely** helpful aid to Haskell programming: whilst you technically speaking don't need them, a very common work-flow is:

1. Specify the type a function *should* have
2. Add a definition
3. Attempt to load the file into ghci
4. Fix any type errors that may occur.

## EDIT1

The version that matches the edit in the original question is:

```
work :: Int -> [Int] -> IO String
work n b = do
  if n == 0 
    then 
        return $ unwords (map show b)
    else do 
        line <- getLine
        work (n-1) $ summ (map toInts $ words line) b
```

An improved variant is:

```
work :: Int -> [Int] -> IO String
work 0 bs = return . unwords $ map show bs
work n bs = do line <- getLine
               work (n-1) $ summ (map toInts $ words line) b
```

Note also that your definition of `summ` is incorrect as it uses `++` when it should use `:` (and is in fact identical to `zipWith (+)`).

Comment: now I get src\Main.hs:27:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: [String]
    In the expression: return $ unwords (map show b)
    In the expression:
      if n == 0 then
            return $ unwords (map show b)
      else
          do { line <- getLine;
               work (n - 1) (summ toInts . words line b) }

Comment: @RustemMustafin: if you want `work` to return a `String` value, then you can't use `getLine` in it: it is of type `IO String`, in which case your type signature won't match the else-case.  If you want to call `getLine` in `work`, then the result of `work` should be `IO String`.

Comment: sorry, but I can't get it: the work function reads the line, breaks it to words, converts to [Int] and then sums up with previous result n-times. If n = 0 it returns resulting [Int] converted to string "a b c".
What excatly is wrong in using getLine in the middle of this  function? I do not want getLine to affect return-type of this function in any way, is there possibility to do so?

Comment: @RustemMustafin: in your edit, you have specified that `work` has a type of `Int -> [Int] -> String`; as such, this makes it a pure, non-IO function.  The "monad" that is then in is the list monad (since `String = [Char]`), and thus within this function `return :: Char -> String`.  But, `getLine` operations in the **IO** monad, which you need to specify in the type signature.  Note also that you probably want the last line to have `(summ toInts $ words line b)`, note the `$` instead of the `.`.

Comment: Also, note, that the else-clause matches the return-type String, as far as it is the call to work, which should return String.

Comment: @RustemMastafin: OK, I've updated my answer to take into account your changes (note also that my previous comment on how to fix the last line was wrong).  It doesn't matter that the recursive call has the correct type (as it should...) but if you want to use IO *within* a function, then the function should be in the IO monad.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to improve my code. In case You have some links where this "monad" behviour, please feel free to share =)

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
work n b = do
  if n == 0 
    then 
        unwords (map show b)
    else do 
        line <- getLine
        work n-1 summ (map toInt . unwords line) b
```

The last line there should probably be

```
        work (n-1) (summ (map toInt . unwords line) b)
```

Note the extra brackets.

There are probably other errors as well.